# Can't see result of application/json output with PHP

Tags: php, json, nginx

I'm building a very simple API in PHP to give me data from my DB in `application/json` format.

Here is my `muscular-groups.php` file :

```
<?php

include '../inc/db.php';

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $req = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM muscular_groups WHERE id = ?');
    $req->execute([$_GET['id']]);
    $res = $req->fetchAll();
}
else {
    $req = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM muscular_groups');
    $req->execute();
    $res = $req->fetchAll();
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($res);
```

The problem is that in local all works well as you can see below :
[image]

But when I want to access it on my server (at `www.example.com/api/muscular-groups`), I have a white screen without any error message or error logs.

What is strange : If I replace `header('Content-Type: application/json');` and `echo json_encode($res);` with `var_dump($res)` in `muscular-groups.php`, it appears on the screen.

P.S.: very strange, only one of my endpoints works on my server (eg: `www.example.com/api/offers`) and displays a json output, here's the code :

```
<?php

include '../inc/db.php';

$req = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM offers');
$req->execute();
$res = $req->fetchAll();

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($res);
```

I'm lost...

Comment: First question: What version of PHP is running on your server that does not work?

Comment: Suggestion: Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php/845025#845025) to the
top of your file(s) _while running on the server that does not work_ right after your opening PHP tag for example
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see if it yields anything.

Comment: @RiggsFolly my php version is 5.6.17-0+deb8u1. I already tried it, but nothing appears. Also in my php-fpm php.ini file but it seems to be already enabled.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I tried your suggestion anyway, but nothing happened too :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it : the problem was there was UTF-8 characters, and PDO was not configured to give them as-is. So `$pdo->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8'");` saved my life!